# Swift 4 - Enable/Disable Two UI Buttons Based On Different TextField Inputs

Tags: input, uibutton, textfield

I feel like I'm missing a basic step with this code set and really would appreciate any insight since I couldn't find a great solution despite searching these forums.

I have four textfields, two UI buttons, and two labels.

When the first three textfields have input, one of the UI buttons should be enabled allowing me to calculate the sum of those three textfields and display it on the first label.

The second UI button should only be enabled if the fourth textfield has input. The second label will contain the sum of all four textfields. If these conditions aren't met, the UI buttons should be disabled.

I have the first situation working great, but things get messed up when I try to incorporate the fourth text field and second button. See the last snippet: let regurgVTI = AIVTI.text, !regurgVTI.isEmpty

class AICalc: UIViewController
{

```
@IBOutlet weak var PISARadius: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var aliasingVelocity: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var AIVMax: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var AIVTI: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var EROAAnswer: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var RegurgVolumeAnswer: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var calcEROAButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var regurgVolumeButton: UIButton!

@IBAction func calcEROA(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    EROAAnswer.text = String(Int(PISARadius.text!)! + Int(aliasingVelocity.text!)! + Int(AIVMax.text!)!)
}

@IBAction func calcRegurgVolume(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    RegurgVolumeAnswer.text = String(Int(PISARadius.text!)! + Int(aliasingVelocity.text!)! + Int(AIVMax.text!)! + Int(AIVTI.text!)!)
}

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    calcEROAButton.isEnabled = false
    regurgVolumeButton.isEnabled = false
    PISARadius.addTarget(self, action: #selector(editingChanged(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
    aliasingVelocity.addTarget(self, action: #selector(editingChanged(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
    AIVMax.addTarget(self, action: #selector(editingChanged(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
    AIVTI.addTarget(self, action: #selector(editingChanged(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@objc func editingChanged(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if textField.text?.count == 1 {
        if textField.text?.first == " " {
            textField.text = ""
            return
        }
    }
    guard
        let pisa = PISARadius.text, !pisa.isEmpty,
        let aliasing = aliasingVelocity.text, !aliasing.isEmpty,
        let vmax = AIVMax.text, !vmax.isEmpty
        else {
            calcEROAButton.isEnabled = false
            regurgVolumeButton.isEnabled = false
            return
    }
    calcEROAButton.isEnabled = true

  let regurgVTI = AIVTI.text, !regurgVTI.isEmpty

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use textField.tag or textField.identifier to identify textfield then you can solve your problem easily.

Let say your 1st three textfields have tag 1,2,3 simultaneously.

Then in your textfield did end_Enditing :-

```
if textfield.tag == 1 {
      //Do whatever you want
}
if textfield.tag == 2 {
      //Do whatever you want
}
if textfield.tag == 3 {
      //Do whatever you want
}
```

Referring this may solve your problem.
Best luck.